# mapping dictionary value to list and return original value if key doesn't exist

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list seems like this :

`a = ['jokowi','jokowidodo','ir h jokowidodo','teungku']`

and a dictionary like this

`{'jokowi': 'jokowi', 'jokowidodo': 'jokowi', 'ir h jokowidodo': 'jokowi'}`

and make a mapping using this code:

`list(map(data_dict.get,listakoh))`

and then it returns:

`['jokowi', 'jokowi', 'jokowi', None]`

the question is how can I replace `None` in the result with the original value of my previous list, so `None` in the result must be `'teungku'`

Comment: Please add a tag for the programming language :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a second argument to `get` as a default value:

```
list(map(lambda x: data_dict.get(x, x), a))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define your own function and map that.

```
a = ['jokowi','jokowidodo','ir h jokowidodo','teungku']
d = {'jokowi': 'jokowi', 'jokowidodo': 'jokowi', 'ir h jokowidodo': 'jokowi'}

def f(k):
    global d
    try:
        return d[k]
    except KeyError:
        return k

r = list(map(f, a))
print(r)

['jokowi', 'jokowi', 'jokowi', 'teungku']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily compare the mapped list with the original list and replace the None values with those from the actual list.

```
>>> new_list = list(map(data_dict.get,listakoh))
>>> for index, element in enumerate(new_list):
    if element == None:
        new_list[index]=a[index]

>>> print(new_list)
['jokowi', 'jokowi', 'jokowi', 'teungku']
```